# SP2013 Image Gallery Using Slider

Tags: web-part-gallery

I need to display a list in a design attached but not sure what tools to use.

The employee list will have the columns:
EmpID
Fullname
JobTitle
Career
BioImageUrl

[image]

Tiled icons are clickable images with load the details to the employee canvas. Was thinking to hook up the EmpID field to search the list and update employee canvass.

Any big hints how to do this?

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried anything? Post some code what you have tried?

Comment: Have started the employee list but no to coding. Was thinking if someone can give me a start rather me experimenting the unknown.

Comment: You need to use CQWP webpart and in CQWP webpart you have to use slider of any javascript.

Comment: Thanks for the head. The keywords lead me direct to this post http://goo.gl/b4CV6B.